# React app triggers "Your connection is not private"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

So when I `npm start` my React app I keep getting this message in Chrome. Is there anything I can do to my app so this doesn't come up anymore?

[image]

---

***UPDATE***: I know I can get around this on the Chrome side by enabling the flag `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` but it'd be nice to be able to fix this from the app so every dev now and in the future wouldn't have to deal with setting Chrome flags.

Comment: Seems like it's a problem with the browser's settings, have you tried the IP 127.0.0.1 ?
Also, try going to Network settings in Windows and setting your current network to Private status.

Comment: Are you using SSL certs that are self-signed?

Comment: @zero298 I have no idea. How would I find that out?

Comment: Oh, you're serving on localhost, you have to be using self-signed SSL.   You won't be able to get around this issue as long as you are trying to access your app at `https://localhost` or whatever.  The warning is to tell you that the browser doesn't have a certificate proving that the connection you are making is genuine but as long as it's localhost, there is no point in doing certs for it.  Try accessing with `http://` instead of `https://`.  As long as you aren't  using any https only JS features, it shouldn't matter.  Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: @zero298 Oh that makes sense! Yes I'm using create-react-app.